# Using 2 where queries with streambuilder Flutter firebase returns null

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using 2 where queries in Streambuilder flutter Firebase. It gets the docs as a stream but it updates again and turns it to null. example code:

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                .collection('events')
                .where(
                  'asTimeStamp',
                  isLessThan: DateTime.now(),
                )
                .where(
                  'isVerified',
                  isEqualTo: true,
                )
                .limit(20)
                .snapshots(),
```

Comment: You need a composite index setup in firebase firestore for this to work. Check out https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing. Also, you must be getting an error from firebase sdk in your run logs where you are presented with a url to auto create the required composite query.